# Ratio of the distance of two percentiles

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, percentile

Consider two sample means $\bar{X_1}$ and $\bar{X_2}$ from the same normal population having mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.  The first sample mean is based on $n_1 = 10^k$ observations, while the second is based on $n_2 = 10^{k+2}$ observation for some positive integer $k$.  Take any percentile, say $100 * \alpha$, from the distribution of the means for each sample size excluding the median.  What is the ratio of the distance of the two percentiles from $\mu$ dividing distance 1 by distance 2?

---

I need help breaking this question down.  I understand that we initially have two sample means from the same population.  I understand that both samples are based on different sample sizes involving 10 raised to some power of k for the first sample, and k+1 for the second.

But I start to lose the thread after this.  Why does the instruction take pains to "exclude the median"?  Is this important, or is this just a red herring?  Are we now considering two samples of sample means, with each sample either belonging to a collection of samples of size $10^k$ and $10^{k+1}$?  And how would I even begin to measure the distance from the mean?  Does this involve standardizing the percentile to a z-score?

Comment: I think "exclude the median" means that the question is about  what happens with values of $\alpha$ that are *not* $50 \%$

Comment: I think the reason for excluding the median is that it is equal to $\mu,$ that is, the distance from $\mu$ is zero, so the ratio of distances would be zero divided by zero.

Comment: $\bar X_1$ and $\bar X_2$ have normal distributions.  Can you state their means and standard deviations in terms of $\mu$, $\sigma$ and $k$.  Then choose some $\mu$, $\sigma$, $k$ and $\alpha\not =50\%$ and find the ratio for that case (for example R's `qnorm()` function might help).  Then choose different   $\mu$, $\sigma$, $k$ and $\alpha\not =50\%$ and be slightly surprised that you get the same ratio.  Then consider why (scaling might be a thought) and identify what that number is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "help breaking this question down" as you asked, here are some general steps:

1. Choose any $\alpha$ which is different than 50%, e.g. $\alpha=0.05$. This is important because your population is normal, hence the (population) mean is equal to the (population) median and the distance would be zero if you were to use $\alpha=0.5$.
2. You can calculate the percentiles $p_1$ and $p_2$ using a formula which involves the parameters of your distribution, $\alpha$, and the sample sizes $n_1$ and $n_2$ respectively. (Think of what the percentiles represent, and that should help you choose the apropriate function to use for this step.)

Editing to add some sub-steps for step 2:

- First, write what the distributions of $\bar X_1$ and $\bar X_2$ are;
- You will find that the variances differ (intuitively, since the second sample has more data, you anticipate that the variance for $\bar X_2$ will be smaller);
- Then, write the formula for the percentiles for each sample; although these are "ugly", most of this will simplify in the next step.

3. Calculating the ratio of the distances should then be fairly straightforward (because when subtracting $\mu$, most of the remaining terms cancel out): you should be left with a constant, due to the fact that n2/n1 is a constant.

Comment: I have to apologize, but I don't really see where this is going.  Why can't I just take a ratio of standardized z-scores?  Then the ratio would be 1.  And yet the solution provided says it is not 1.

Comment: Ok, I thought about it some more, and I think I figured it out.  In a standard normal distribution, we can measure distance using $\mu + z_{\alpha}* \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$.  This simplifies to $- z_{\alpha}* \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.  If I let $k=1$ and let $z = -1.645$ (which should be the case if $\alpha = 0.05$, then skipping forward a few steps I should arrive at $\frac{10\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{10}}$ which gives me a ratio of 10.

Comment: Let me add some sub-steps in step 2, which I think is what you might be missing, but you sound on the right path...

Comment: Looking forward to it.  Also, please note that I just realized I made a mistake with sample 2's size.  It's actually 10 raised to the power of k+2.

Comment: I just edited the answer, I hope these extra sub-steps help. If you follow the steps, you should easily be able to generalize to any k. Happy exploring!